# How to modify Cache-Control of a Plesk Server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, plesk, cache-control

My server is a Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS server running Plesk version 12.0.18. Even though I tried to modify Cache-Control in .htaccess and in httpd.conf, the website on the server returns the same Cache-Control header: "max-age=0, no-cache". Where can I find the file which stores this setting and how can I make a permanent change which does not get overwritten by any auto re-generation of the file?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have nginx enabled. In this case you should specify your Cache-Control settings in “Additional nginx directives” in Web Server Settings.